# Math/Statistical analysis of a video on youtube

Tags: arithmetic

Say approx 6.3 billion people in the world:

> 6300000000

And the youtube video has 290 million views:

> 290000000

What percentage of people (of the world) have seen this video?

Answer (score 2):

Easy peasy, just couldnt get it into my head.

Just used a simple example instead to understand the logic:

10 people in the world, 2 people watch the video, what percentage of people watch the video.

> 2/10 = 0.2
>
> 0.2 * 100 = 20%

Cross over this logic:

> 290000000/6300000000 = 0.046031746031746
>
> 0.046031746031746 * 100 = 4.603174603174603 = 4.6%.

Meaning..

**4.6%** of the world have watched the video.

Comment: This could also be off by a ton. What if the same person watched the video dozens of times, like is the case for many of them. Also, some people wrote programs to run the video to increase the number of views. So, beware of statistics!

Comment: Yes, I discussed this. It is a flaw, but I was more concerned about the logic, more than the real world implications